# pythonの文字コード変換する

Tags: python

日本語で取得したツイートをCSVで出力する際に、文字化けします。
utf_8の代わりにshift_jisに変換しても文字化けします。
文字化けしない方法あれば、教えていただけますでしょうか。
お手数ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

```
#ツイート取得
tweet_data = []

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name = "beechhangergals",exclude_replies = True).items():
    tweet_data.append([tweet.id,tweet.created_at,tweet.text.replace('\n',''),tweet.favorite_count,tweet.retweet_count])

#csv出力
with open('tweets.csv', 'w',newline='',encoding='utf_8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text","fav","RT"])
    writer.writerows(tweet_data)
pass
```

Comment: 文字化けとのことですが、どのような確認方法でしょうか？ 確認方法に問題はないのでしょうか？

Comment: この記事 [Tweepyでツイートを取得](https://qiita.com/i_am_miko/items/a2e5168e619ed37afeb9) に非常に似ていますが、何か動作環境等に違いがあるのかもしれません。あるいは最近までに何かの仕様が変わったとか。

Comment: もし Linux / macOS 環境であれば、`nkf --guess tweets.csv` で文字コードと改行コードを確認できます。これを用いて、まずは `tweets.csv` が UTF-8 なのかを確認していただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございました。csvを開くと日本語のみtextだけ次の通りになります。荳也阜縺ｧ陦後″縺溘＞蝗ｽ縺ｯｼ溘≠繧翫∪縺吶°ｼ溟汞ｺｸ縲㍑㌃縲㌃ｷ縲㌍ｷ縲㌶㌻縲㌣㌀縲㌕ｸ縲陦後″縺ｾ縺励ｇ縺ｼ

Comment: 「世界で行きたい国は〜」と言うテキストが正しくUTF-8で表現されているのを **無理やりSJISとして開くと** そのような文字列になります。「csvを開くと」と言うのはどのように開いているのでしょうか? Excelや一部のテキストエディターは何も指定しないと正しいUTF-8のテキスト(CSV)を開くことが出来ないのですが、そう言ったものを使っているのではありませんか?

Comment: （UTF-8）設定で開くとこのように表示されます。

Comment: 1.1669E+18 2019/8/29 2:45 ・ｼ純邱繧∝・繧翫∪縺ｧ縺ゅ→2譌･純・丈ｸ也阜縺ｮ縺翫∩繧・￡ 3000蜀・・繧ｯ繝ｼ繝昴Φ縺・0蜷阪↓蠖薙◆繧・#繝励Ξ繧ｼ繝ｳ繝医く繝｣繝ｳ繝壹・繝ｳ 髢句ぎ荳ｭ(ﾂｴ繝ｮ` )3荳也阜荳ｭ縺ｮ螳夂分縺九ｉ繝ｬ繧｢縺ｪ縺翫∩繧・￡

Comment: 「csvを開くと」と言うのはどのように開いているのでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntuの場合、lessとfileを以下でインストール可能です:

```
apt install less file
```

実行のテストを高速化させるため、以下の部分を修正してください:

```py
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,screen_name = "beechhangergals",exclude_replies = True).items():
    tweet_data.append([tweet.id,tweet.created_at,tweet.text.replace('\n',''),tweet.favorite_count,tweet.retweet_count])
    break #breakを追加し、実行のテストを高速化する
```

次にスクリプトを実行し、以下のコマンドで開きます。

```
less tweets.csv
```

すると日本語が正常に表示されるはずです。文字のエンコードを確かめるためには以下を実行します:

```
file -i tweets.csv
```

[出力]

```
tweets.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

つまり、このスクリプトを実行することによって生成されるcsvのエンコードはutf-8です。

pythonのバージョンを確認するために、以下を実行します:

```
python --version
```

もし、バージョンが2系であれば、3系を試してください。

```
apt install python3 python3-pip
python3 script.py
```

2019/10/08 時点では、少なくともtweepyのバージョンが `tweepy==3.8.0` であればスクリプトの実行は成功します。バージョンを最新にするために以下を実行してください。

```
pip3 install -U tweepy
```

Excelを使わずに、lessコマンド等で見るか、あるいはEmacsやVimのようなエディタで開いて試してください。

もしこれらを行っても文字化けする場合、OSの言語設定を確認してください。Ubuntuの場合、言語設定の詳細は以下で確認できます:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-language.html.en

Comment: ありがとうございます。設定できました。